# Why doesn't stackoverflow.com jQuery script block the rendering in Google PageSpeed insight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, pagespeed

I'm new to SEO and was trying to optimize my pages speed with [Google PageSpeed insights tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights).

The tool found that my page:

> has 2 blocking script resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

```
<!-- Google PageSpeed insights triggers warning for the 2 scripts -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/public/views/js/temp.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    Test Page!
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that because I didn't `DEFER` the script or `ASYNC` it, the browser will pause rendering the page until those two blocking scripts are downloaded. [Source](https://pegasaas.com/deferring-javascript-can-dramatically-speed-up-website/).

But what really suprised me that [the same tool didn't trigger](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com) that warning with the jQuery script for [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), it only complains for the `stub.en.js` file!

```
<!-- Google PageSpeed insights doesn't trigger the warning for the jQuery script -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- code has been ommited-->
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=ff08f1bc5114"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does my jQuery script block the rendering while stackoverflow.com jQuery script doesn't, although both pages don't have the `defer` or `async` attributes?**